# Автоматические сообщения на сайте

Tags: php, sql

делаю сообщения на сайте: структура mySQL:

```
id
to_id
from_id
timestamp_created
text
```

Делаю выборку так:

```
SELECT `id`, `to_id`, `owner_id`, `timestamp_created`, `type`, `text` 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE (:owner_id, :to_id) IN ((`owner_id`, `to_id`), (`to_id`, `owner_id`))
```

Сообщения работают но мне нужно сделать все это на Ajax.
Как определить где новые сообщения и вообще вес ь алгоритм не ясен.

Comment: *Как определить где новые сообщения* По значению поля `timestamp_created`

Answer (score 0):

Для определения "новых сообщений" для текущего пользователя, я бы добавил поле "прочитано?":

```
`is_read`
```

Обычно в мессенджерах есть метка для отправителя, показывающая, прочитано сообщение или нет. Этот флаг тут пригодится.
Не помешает составной индекс по 2 столбцам:

```
`owner_id`, `is_read`
```

Когда будет много сообщений, это позволит быстрее доставать непрочитанные сообщения текущего пользователя.
И отсортировал бы по столбцам в запросе:

```
`to_id` ASC, `timestamp_created` ASC
```

для разделения сообщений по разным получателям.
По-поводу ajax не понял, как удобно - так и доставайте на фронт данные из БД.